# How can I prevent my laptop from sleeping (suspending) automatically when idle?

Tags: gnome, suspend, dell

My laptop suspends (sleeps) automatically after several minutes without use. I usually let the laptop download stuff and go to sleep then I wake and find nothing was downloaded and the laptop is sleeping which is not awesome.

**How do I stop my laptop from auto-suspending and make it only suspend when I tell it to?**

- Laptop model: DELL inspiron-3542
- OS: UBUNTU 17.10
- Desktop environment: GNOME 3.26.1

I have this in startup applications:

[image: Startup applications]

GNOME tweaks power options:

[image: GNOME tweaks power options]

System summary:

[image: System info]

Power options: [image]
[image]

Contents of `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
# This file is part of systemd.
#
# systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```